# Objective C: Methods Can't See One Another?

Tags: objective-c, methods, function-pointers, encapsulation

I'm a total newby with Objective-C, so bear with me. I'm not looking for a code handout, but some guidance on where to look for answers would be appreciated.

I'm a motion picture editor and I prototyped a small utility in Python which reads an Edit Decision List (which is a text tile with timecodes and various other pieces of information  pertinent to video editing) and parses the file one line at a time and extracts certain information to create a subtitle list.

Once I got it working in Python, I made the brash decision to migrate the code to Objective-C so I could distribute my utility to other editors as a binary executable.

So much for the backstory, now for the question...

Last night I managed to build the GUI, which is a simple button to initiate a file requester (to load the text file) a button to convert the file, and a button to save the newly converted file. There's also a text view object to display the converted file. I managed to attach all widgets to the new class and I can test for each button being clicked, and I can manually write text to the text view widget. So far, all's good.

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to pass information from one method to another. In particular, if I open the file using the openFile method, then how do I pass that information to the convertFile method? When I try, I get a message telling me that my openFile is undefined. I assume it's all about data encapsulation. But it's frustrating as heck, and I'm such a newbie, I'm not even sure what I should be looking at for answers. It was very easy in Python: any method in a given class seemed to allow for seamless transfer to any other method without problems.

To recap, I do have the file requester opening, and I'm able to read the file. I can even parse it line by line. But it's in it's own method, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pass that information later to the "convert" method and after that how to pass the converted file to the "save" method.

Guidance MUCH appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Chris Conlee

Comment: What do you mean by "pass information"?  There's many different ways to do information passing in OOP, as I'm sure you're aware coming from Python.  Perhaps you meant calling methods, or instantiating classes for use later?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. Specifically, I call a method which opens a file requester and simply collects a path and file name. Then, the user is able to click on a "Convert File" button which calls a new method and in that method I'd simply like to be able to recall the path and file name from the earlier method so I can open the file and parse it. I'm reading up on @property declarations now, which I think is the lead I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjC is not all that different from Python in this respect. In both languages, data can be associated with an object, local to a function/method, or global. You can pass data directly from one method to another as arguments, or indirectly by storing it somewhere that both methods have access to (for example, an instance variable).

For the former, you would do something like this (hypothetical implementation filled in, since I don't know what your methods do):

```
@implementation MyClass //in the .m
- (void) openFile:(NSString *)pathToFile {
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];
    [self convertFile:fileData];
}

- (void) convertFile:(NSData *)fileData {
    //whatever you wanted to do to fileData
}
@end
```

For the latter, you'd need to declare storage on the object for the thing you want to store, as well as how that storage should be accessed. Modern ObjC combines these tasks with the `@property` syntax:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject //in the .h
@property (readwrite, strong) NSData *fileData;
@end

@implementation MyClass //in the .m
- (void) openFile:(NSString *)pathToFile {
    self.fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];
}

- (void) convertFile {
    //whatever you wanted to do to self.fileData
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Specifically, in my Python script my "Get EDL" button simply opened a file requester and collected a path and file name and displayed said path/filename in a text box.

Then, my "Convert File" method retrieved the previously collected path/filename and began parsing the file one line at a time. That's where my headaches began...

From "getEDL":

NSURL* filePath = [[openDlg URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
            
            NSString *tempPath = filePath.path;

Now I'd simply like to open tempPath in my convert method. Seems simple, but my head hurts.

Comment: That sounds like you want nearly exactly my second example. Store the path as a property, access that property as self.propertyName in both methods.

Comment: I'm studying up on @property right now in Kochan's book, 5th edition. Sounds like what I'm looking for. Will report back as I make progress. Frustrating; I feel like I take 1 step foward, and 3/4 step back every time I try something new. But I'll get there. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: By using the @property declaration I was able to pass my path and file name to my convert method. Haven't finished my code yet, but I'm back to making forward progress. Thanks a million!